# How can you check if there is a word in a password?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, passwords

I am currently programming a password generator. It only contains letters. Let's assume that it randomly generates a password with a word in it. How can I make sure that doesn't happen? Is there a library with a dictionary for this?

So that no password like this is generated, for example:
xlhello

Comment: what you describe as word? dictionary word ?

Comment: There are natural language processing libraries, they include lists of words.

Comment: Does that exclude any password with "I" or "a" in it? Those are *words*… "me"? "he"?

Comment: `if any(word in password for word in list_of_words):`

Comment: You should probably only check for words longer than some threshold.

Comment: Consider that a randomly formed word is still *random*. It might be bad if the password consists *exclusively* of a word with no extra characters, but a word randomly appearing within a longer random string is still both random and pretty unlikely. Consider that it also narrows the search field for an attacker if they know they can *exclude* all dictionary words from their attack…

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html) is what you are looking for

```
import nltk
nltk.download('words')
from nltk.corpus import words

list_of_words = list(filter(lambda x: len(x)!=1, words.words()))  #filtering out single letter alphabets, since all passwords would have at least one alphabet 

def isWordinPassword(password):
    #accepts string password and returns list of words that exist in the password
    words_in_password = list(filter(lambda x: x in password, list_of_words))
    return words_in_password


password = "xsdhello"
isWordinPassword(password)
```

A screenshot of the output:

[image]

I have used lambda and filter functions. You can read more about them [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-filter-python-examples/)

Comment: You can create rules and reduce the `list_of_words`.

Comment: Is it actually possible to check other languages?

Comment: Yes checkout https://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html#corpora-in-other-languages